# Kendo UI Scheduler disable remove confirm or change its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am using a `Kendo UI Scheduler`. Now, when I want to remove an item from the scheduler, a popup will show up and wants a confirmation:

[image: see picture]

I do not need this confirmation, but it seems, that there is no attribute to disable it.

If there is no direct solution to this, it would be also fine with me to change the content of the dialog. To do this I tried to get the `ready event` when the dialog shows up. But none of the solutions listed below worked.

```
//k-window-title is a css class of the popup
$(document).on("ready", ".k-window-title", function () {
    console.log("1");
});

$(".k-window-title").ready(function () {
    console.log("2");
});

$(".k-window-title").fadeIn(1000, function () {
    console.log("3");
});
```

I also have a event added to the attribute `remove`, but this only does some things with a Kendo Grid, which is also displayed on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desired action: Click an event's 'x' button to immediately remove the event from the schedule.

You didn't show the scheduler component configuration code, but you want to have

```
  editable: {
    confirmation: false
  },
```

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler/configuration/editable.confirmation